# How add feature in a different projection in Openlayers 3.5

Tags: openlayers-3

I'm using Openlayer 3.5 and load an OSM map "EPSG:3857".

```
var extent = [116.826673, 4.854776, 126.748593, 18.697146];
var philiExtent = ol.extent.applyTransform(extent, ol.proj.getTransform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"));

var view = new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.transform([121.787633, 11.775961], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
    zoom: 0,
    extent: philiExtent,
    resolutions: [2560, 1280, 640, 320, 160, 80, 40, 20, 10, 5, 2.5, 1.2, 0.6],
});

var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    target: 'map'
});
```

But my features from webService are in "EPSG:4326"

```
function showData(data) {
    var format = new ol.format.WKT();
    var feature;
    $.each(data, function (i, link) {
        feature = format.readFeature(link.geom);
        wktTraffic.addFeature(feature);
    })
    console.log('done load map');
}
```

So how I make the map be on 4326 or the new feature be on 3857.
I prefer first option.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the FAQ section: http://openlayers.org/en/master/doc/faq.html#how-do-i-change-the-projection-of-my-map-

How do I change the projection of my map?
There is a good chance that you want to change the default projection of OpenLayers to something more appropriate for your region or your specific data.

The projection of your map can be set through the view-property. Here are some examples:

// OpenLayers comes with support for the World Geodetic System 1984, EPSG:4326:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: 'EPSG:4326'
    // other view properties like map center etc.
  })
  // other properties for your map like layers etc.
});

// To use other projections, you have to register the projection in OpenLayers:
//
// By default OpenLayers does not know about the EPSG:21781 (Swiss) projection.
// So we create a projection instance for EPSG:21781 and pass it to
// ol.proj.addProjection to make it available to the library for lookup by its
// code.
var swissProjection = new ol.proj.Projection({
  code: 'EPSG:21781',
  // The extent is used to determine zoom level 0. Recommended values for a
  // projection's validity extent can be found at http://epsg.io/.
  extent: [485869.5728, 76443.1884, 837076.5648, 299941.7864],
  units: 'm'
});
ol.proj.addProjection(swissProjection);

// we can now use the projection:
var map = new ol.Map({
  view: new ol.View({
    projection: swissProjection
    // other view properties like map center etc.
  })
  // other properties for your map like layers etc.
});
```

We recommend to lookup parameters of your projection (like the validity extent) over at epsg.io.

Comment: Doesnt work for me. If i add projection the base map doesnt even appear

Comment: OSM is not available in EPSG:4326

Answer (score 2):

To reproject your features to `EPSG:3857`, you can set the options `dataProjection` and `featureProjection` when parsing the features from the WKT string. See also [ol.format.WKT#readFeature](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.format.WKT.html#readFeature)

```
var format = new ol.format.WKT();
var feature;
$.each(data, function (i, link) {
    feature = format.readFeature(link.geom, {
      dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326',
      featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'
    });
    wktTraffic.addFeature(feature);
})
```